# Fetch Keywords from comment and assign keyword id to comment

Tags: performance, php, functional-programming, laravel

I have a small callback function which receives a **comment in array** like below:

```
                        $data[$count] = array(
                            'comment_id' => $comment['id'],
                            'comment_body' => $comment['message'],
                            'comment_author_id' => $comment['from']['id'],
                            'comment_author_name' => $comment['from']['name'],
                            'active' => 1,
                            'keyword_id' => null,
                            'live_video_id' => $liveVideo->live_vidoe_id
                        );
```

the I send this comment to a function **AssignKeywords** as below:

`$data = array_map([$this , 'assignKeywords'], $data);`

Below is the definition of **AssignKeywords**

```
public function assignKeywords($comment)
{
    # code...
    $keywords = Keyword::where('live_video_id' , $comment['live_video_id'])->get();
    $commentBody = strtolower($comment['comment_body']);
    preg_match_all('/(?<!\w)#\w+/',$commentBody,$matches); //it returns an associative array with just 0 index and array of matches on this 0 index

    foreach($matches as $match) {   //only 1
        foreach ($match as $item) {    //max 10 if a user is mad :\
            foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {   //Max 4
                $keywordBody = strtolower($keyword['keyword_name']);
                if ($item === $keywordBody) {
                    if ($comment['keyword_id'] == NULL) { //to check if it already contains a value, if it contains we don't want to assign again
                        $comment['keyword_id'] = $keyword['id'];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $comment;
}<br>
```

I am looking for a better way to Assign Keywords and minimize **foreach** loops and maybe solve it by using functions? Any thoughts?

Comment: It might be useful for you  to add more context (for example the entire class that is involved here) in order to get more meaningful review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From performance point of view, 40 iterations is nothing.

However, given such a condition that your keywords are like the Highlanders, as there could be only one, the number of repetitions could be reduced as we won't need anymore after we get one.

```
foreach($matches as $match) {   //only 1
    foreach ($match as $item) {    //max 10 if a user is mad :\
        foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {   //Max 4
            $keywordBody = strtolower($keyword['keyword_name']);
            if ($item === $keywordBody) {
                    $comment['keyword_id'] = $keyword['id'];
                    break 3; // stop all loops
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```